# Base64ToHex() on code sample

Tags: c#, api

I'm reading this code [sample](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001267.html):

And since I don't know C#, I decided to give it a go.

While compiling I've got this message:

```
Main.cs(32,65): error CS1061: Type `string' does not contain a definition for `Base64ToHex' and no extension method `Base64ToHex' of type `string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

I've look in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_members.aspx) and as expected I didn't find a reference for that method.

Question: Where did that method came from?

p.s. My code looks like:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System;

class MainClass
{ 
    public static string Encrypt(string toEncrypt, string key, bool useHashing)
    {
         ..... // same as in post
         .....
    }

    public static void Main( string [] args )
    {
        string key = "secret";

        Console.WriteLine( Encrypt("oscar" + "000", key, true ).Base64ToHex() );
    }
```

}

Comment: That method call is in the code of something you are reading?

Comment: They might have a reference to a library that they wrote an extention method called Base64ToHex()

Comment: @CSharpAlt: Yes, the link is in the post. It is in the second code segment: 
Debug.WriteLine(
    Encrypt("try some different" +
    "00000000000000000000000000000000",
    key, true).Base64ToHex());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that code ever complied, Jeff probably had an extension method on String called "Base64ToHex".  [Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) allow you to define methods to "extend" other classes, such that it appears that the method was actually defined in that class:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string Base64ToHex(this string str)
    {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more likely. I didn't knew about extensions methods. They could be added only to non-final classes I guess, and I guess string is non final, am I right? What's with the "static" access modifier ? Is it needed? What does an static class means?

Comment: The String class is sealed (The "final" access modifier is Java.  Same thing.).  That's what's nice about extension methods - they allow you to extend "non-extendable" classes.  The method must be static, but the class need not be.  A static class is one that cannot be instantiated (so that you aren't tempted to do it, accidentally).

Comment: To amplify, you can declare an extension method anywhere you like, as long as you reference the containing class (with a using statement) when you call the method.  I like to group my extension methods (I don't have a lot of them) by function, and not just put them willy-nilly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `Base64ToHex` method in `System.String`. I think you're looking for [Convert.FromBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx) and [BitConverter.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a733s97.aspx):

```
string encrypted = Encrypt("oscar" + "000", key, true);
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted)));
```

---

I took a look at your link, and I'm guessing he wrote a helper extension method that does the same:

```
public static string Base64ToHex(this string s)
{
    return BitConverter.ToString(Convert.FromBase64String(s));
}
```